# Weight loss conundrum

Tags: weight-loss, muscle-gain, chest, back, arms

I want to know how I can **lose fat** and **gain muscle** simultaneously.

This is my current situation.

1. I have fat chest.
2. I have small arms.
3. Fat stomach.
4. Belly fat in back.

I am going to gym four days per week. Do the gym schedule well.

**Gym Schedule**.

**Day 1**

Biceps,Chest,Shoulders, circuit training and Abs.

**Day 2**

Triceps, Back,Circuit training and Abs.

But still I do not I achieve my goals.

I want to know is this schedule is fine for me?

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I want to know technique which I am doing is fine?

Comment: you are not training your legs.... training legs can speed up fat loss. Also try training your entire body at once, there's no reason to split it in different days unless you have health related problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Weight loss**

Weight loss comes from eating less calories than your body needs. If a 90 kg man needs 3000 calories to maintain his fat then he needs to eat 2800 calories to lose around 0.2 kilograms a week. 
The most commonly used method is to eat 200-500 calories less than needed.

**Muscle building**

Progressive overload is the name of the game

The body builds bigger muscle to withstand stress, bigger stress=bigger muscles. If your muscles are not growing then try increasing the sets,repetitions,weight,speed,[time under tension](https://www.t-nation.com/training/new-science-of-time-under-tension) or the rest between sets.

Since you asked about which rep range to do, The truth is that it really doesn't matter for muscle building. Low reps build strength and muscle while high reps build endurance and muscle, it all comes down to preference.

[**Biological law of accommodation**](https://weightliftingwithoutlimits.com/2017/01/05/the-biological-law-of-accommodation/)

If you keep giving your body the same type of stress over and over again you will eventually plateau in all senses be it endurance,muscle building or strength, once you plateau if you don't implement any kind of Periodization you will totally stall or worse become weaker and lose muscles because the body no more adapts to stress but ''accommodates'' itself to stress.

People who never did any physical activity in their entire life might be able to train for 1 or 2 years without experiencing any stall.

Keep changing exercises every 2-3 weeks and use a variety of exercises to avoid plateaus.

Example : Bench press> Weighted dips> Weighted push up> Repeat

Comment: Also I want to know number of reps I want to do each excercise? and technique of it.

Comment: what do you mean by ''technique'' ?

Comment: low or high weight and slow or speed reps?

Comment: high weight means you build strength and muscle but you are forced to use low repetitions, low weight  with high repetitions means you will build endurance and muscle both work well. choose based on what you prefer.  Speed reps build explosiveness and power but are not that good for growing muscle.

Comment: 1-5 reps for strength, 20-100 or more for endurance and 10-15 for a little  bit of both